# How Do You Display an External Program From Within Curses?

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I've fallen in love with Vim and a lot of other terminal-based programs. I'm trying to write a shell in Python, using curses. I'd like to have a list of tabs, with background processes running in them (like htop and a terminal-based network manager).

But I can't figure out how to display an external application within a given window/pad of the screen.

Comment: curses only displays what your application tells it to.  You'll have to find how to get the useful information from your application, and display that on the screen.  For that, you need a tutorial (which makes this off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into pseudo terminals. They let your pump the display of one terminal into another. They're used by programs like screen and ssh. I doubt it's (currently) possible with Python, but:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html